# How to count the node a user has created in a View?

Tags: views

I created a view to show **Users**. These users can create nodes of the "Questions" content type.

The view has to render a table to show how many (the total number) Questions the user has created. Something like:

```
User +++ Questions created
John --- 10
Ted  --- 4
Alf  --- 19
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

you have to use the **Aggregation** setting and active it in your view.

1. **Activate Aggregation**. *(It's in the "advanced settings" of the view)*
2. As your view is a view of users, **add the relationship** "*User : content authored*". If you set the option "*Require this relationship*", you'll skip users with no nodes created (can be useful)
3. Add your **user name field**, don't use aggregate
4. **Add a node field**, let's say *Node : nid* **with** the relationship set
5. **Use Aggregate for this field**, "***Count DISTINCT***".

Have fun !

Comment: PS: I hope you're using Drupal 7.

Comment: Make sure the result is sorted by the field you are aggregating, in this example NID

Comment: It works but it shows all the content types. How do I narrow to the "Question" content type?

Comment: Add a filter node : type with the relationship

Answer (score 0):

This question is a variation of what the purpose is of one of the [Out-of-the-box examples](https://www.drupal.org/node/2426921) that you get after install/enable of the [Charts](https://www.drupal.org/project/charts) module, and without any additional configuration.

By doing so, a new view is added to your site. Here are some more details about it, quoted from the linked page above (to which I added some formatting here):

> You can see the charts created via this new view in your own site by
>   navigating to charts/examples or by using a menu link with a title
>   like Charts examples. After doing so, a page is shown with 2 sub-menu
>   tabs:
>
> - the first tab is titled **Built-in examples** (this example is used to
>     showcase [Using the Charts API](https://www.drupal.org/node/233916)).
> - the second tab is titled **Views
>     example**, and is what is created from the new view created during the
>     installation of the charts module. As an alternative to using this
>     tab, just navigate to charts/examples/views in your site. You should
>     then see a column chart and a pie chart, which are followed by a
>     tabular display also. ***Both charts and the table display contain data
>     about the total number of nodes for each of the available content
>     types.***

To massage this out-of-the-box sample to match the question here, all that's needed is to add some appropriate fields (related to the users) and some filter(s), like node type. Done.

Disclosure: I'm the maintainer of this module,
I hope this does not violate the site's [policy on self-promotion](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/faq#promotion).