# Top 10 Commenters this Month

Tags: views, users

We are trying to set up a view that shows a list of top commenters. 
Played around with views but we can't figure it out.

Basically, aggregate all the comments left by each user let say this month.

Then list the usernames in descending order and also show the total number of comments of each user. Next to username for example.

Anyone has ideas on how to do this?

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [this question](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/a/52998/49434). They're doing nearly the same thing but with nodes authored by the user.

After that, you just need to limit the view to 10 results.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Thats a good starting point. The problem though is that I am getting a list of Questions nodes. What I mean by that is that everything is grouped by the node. And I get a number of comments shown for each node. Instead, I am looking to get a total number of comments by USER. 

It doesn't matter which nodes they commented. 

This is close, but I still can't get it to do what I am looking for.

Comment: Sounds like you need to make the view based on users and relate to the comments posted by that user. Not sure what you're talking about with Question nodes unless you're referencing the other question I liked to. If that's not the case, please update your answer to be more clear as to what you are trying to accomplish.

Comment: Our users also comment on Question content type. But unlike the linked answer, we are not trying to group by Question but by user. Total comments by user in all Question Nodes. The issue was that for some reason comments were getting grouped by Question nodes and not by Username.

Comment: I'd recommend taking a look at some views tutorials. With a basic understanding of views and a push in the right direction (such as the issue I linked to) you should have more than enough to get this working. If you're still stuck after that, I would recommend updating your question to more clearly answer what you've tried and specifically what is wrong with that implementation.